# Trouble using DataTemplate in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to make a DataTemplate for a class, NodeList that inherits from ICollection. I want to make a template for displaying all of the "Node" in that list. Each Node also has an "ArcList" class that has "Arc" in it.

I have the following in a Generic.xaml file:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:data="using:SimulationEditor.Data">

<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Arc" x:Key="arcTemplate" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Conditions.Count}"/>
        <Button Content="View Conditions" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Node" x:Key="nodeTemplate" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Arcs}" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource arcTemplate}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I then reference this file my App.xaml file:

```
<Application
x:Class="SimulationEditor.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SimulationEditor">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I am trying to use the data template in another xaml file like this:

```
<ListView Name="lvNodes"
          Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind Component}"
          DoubleTapped="lvNodes_DoubleTapped" 
          SelectionChanged="lvNodes_SelectionChanged"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource nodeTemplate}" />
```

When I compile the code though I get an error, "The XAML Binary Format (XBF) generator reported syntax error '0x09C4' : Property Not Found", in the line with the first data template tag.

How can I fix this compile issue? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: For using binding there is no need for x:Datatype. if you are using x:Bind instead of binding you may need it. Remove x:Datatype and try.

Comment: Can you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)